# Vuejs - Bind Value From Array to Input radio by ID

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'M trying to edit my app. i using `vuejs` for frontend and `Django` for backend.
This image when i creating it.

[image]

However, this's i got when get intial value when trying `update`

[image]

And this is array i got from `backend`

[image][image]

**Any Here My Code**

```
<td colspan="2" class="partner__td">
    <input
        name="twg"
        type="checkbox"
        class="partner__checkbox"
        value="1"
        v-model="form.twg[0]"
    />
    TWG1: Civil Rights and Freedoms<br /><input
        name="twg"
        type="checkbox"
        class="partner__checkbox"
        value="2"
        v-model="form.twg[1]"
    />
    TWG2: Family Environment and Alternative Care
    <br /><input
        name="twg"
        type="checkbox"
        class="partner__checkbox"
        value="3"
        v-model="form.twg[2]"
    />
    TWG3: Basic Health and Welfare
    <br /><input
        name="twg"
        type="checkbox"
        class="partner__checkbox"
        value="4"
        v-model="form.twg[3]"
    />
    TWG4: Education, Leisure and Cultural Activity
    <br /><input
        name="twg"
        type="checkbox"
        class="partner__checkbox"
        value="5"
        v-model="form.twg[4]"
    />
    TWG5: Special Protection Measure
</td>
```

My Problem is when i tried add `v-model=form.twg[0]` input field checkbox will `checked`, I want to make it `checked` by comparing between `form.twg[0].id === 1, 2, 3.. so on` in input field.

Sorry for ma bad english.

`Here my script Code`

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
    name: "PartnerID",
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                twg: [],
            },
        };
    },

    created() {
        this.fetchPartnerID();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchPartnerID() {
            axios
                .get(`api/v1/partner/${this.$route.params.id}`)
                .then((res) => {
                    // this.partner = res.data
                    Vue.set(this.$data, "form", res.data);
                    console.log(res);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.response);
                });
        },

        edit() {
            this.$router.push(`/partner/${this.$route.params.id}/edit`);
        },

        back() {
            this.$router.push(`/partner/`);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Anyway i will appreciate of all ur help....

Comment: Could you please be more clear on your problem?

Comment: can you explain more when you say `I want to make ticked id`

Comment: @KarlL thanks for ur comment. as u can in image, in `twg array 0` `its id is 2 TWG2: Family Environment and Alternative Care`. if i put in `v-model="form.twg[0]` in  `TWG1: Civil Rights and Freedoms` in should be `uncheck`.

Comment: @CamBoKiDz i see. so the issue here is when you v-model a checkbox type input, it will only take values true or false, now any value would result to true ( as long as its not 0, null, undefined etc..) and it would tick/check the input. otherwise false is uncheck. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @KarlL i updated my question bro. pls take alook

Comment: @CamBoKiDz i suggest use a `<select>` field instead, then set `multiple="true"`. and you can v-model like `<select multiple="true" v-model= "form.twg" >...`

Comment: @KarlL okay, but now i try to solve it first. if not, i wll change to `select`

Answer (score 0):

When bound with `v-model`, checkboxes are either checked or not if the variable bound to it `true` or `false`. You'd need to modify your data structure so they contain a property which reflects that.

If you want to only make those checkboxes checked for which you have entries in your array, you need to use a different array or object in you component which would be bound to the checkboxes and be populated from your api results.

[Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox).